# How can I add Interface boundary condition between two domains(geometry) in COMSOL?

Tags: interface, pde, comsol

Please see the attached image/problem[Interface coupled problem statement] below. It has two domains with two PDEs coupled at the interface. I have no problem solving two coupled PDEs for a single geometry, but for two different geometry, I am not sure how can I add two interfaces BCs at the interface of two domains in COMSOL. Can you give me an idea/useful links/example code of how to solve two PDEs in two domains in COMSOL coupled at the interface?

I need to find the variation of two variables(u1 and u2) along the x-axis(1D problem). If you need to know more about the problem,please let me know.

Regards,
Anadi

[Interface coupled problem statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppd2h.png)

Answer (score 0):

In COMSOL, you can use the Multiphysics interface to couple two different domains with different physics. To set up a simulation with two domains that are coupled at the interface, you can create a new model in COMSOL and add two physics interfaces for the two different domains. For example, if you are solving two PDEs, you can add a "PDE" interface for each domain.Then, in each physics interface, define the PDE that you want to solve. later,create a new boundary condition at the interface between the two domains. In this boundary condition, you can specify the coupling between the two domains. For example, you can specify that the values of the variables u1 and u2 are equal at the interface.

Set up the mesh for the model, taking into account the interface between the two domains. You may need to use a finer mesh at the interface to ensure that the solution is accurately captured.Finally, solve the model and post-process the results to visualize the variation of u1 and u2 along the x-axis.

Here is [a link](https://doc.comsol.com/5.5/doc/com.comsol.help.comsol/comsol_ref_modeling.10.36.html) to the COMSOL documentation on coupling different physics interfaces.